# Limitations on <SOH> character in Fix Message

Tags: fix-protocol

In Fix message, `<SOH>` character is used as a delimiter between [tag=value] groups, Is there a problem if I used more than one `<SOH>` character in the FIX message ?.

i.e:

```
tag=value<SOH><SOH><SOH>tag=value

8=FIX.4.2<SOH>9=153<SOH>35=D<SOH><SOH><SOH>49=BLP
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are proposing is not valid FIX.

Sure, some libraries might allow it, but others will (properly) reject it.

Why spend effort doing it wrong?  Just do it right.

Or better yet, don't build it at all.  Use one of the pre-existing open-source FIX engines that are already trusted by developers worldwide.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the FIX library handling the parsing. But this seems a very trivial problem, which almost all libraries might be handling without any problems.. But why would you do it ? The more the library spends computational power on parsing for no apparent gain, you will slow down it's efficiency.